# Laravel 5.1 -Eager Loader me obtiene el ultimo elemento de sub-arreglo

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, model, eloquent

Este es el código..

```html
    public function create()
    {

        $data = ComponenteFormacion::with(['campo_disciplinar'])
            ->get();

        return $data;
}
```

Solo obtengo el último elemento de "campo_disciplinar" (en el ejemplo el último que recibo es "5"), y necesito un arreglo con todos los elementos "campo_disciplinar" que pertenecen a "componente_formacion"

```css
class ComponenteFormacion extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'COMPONENTE_FORMACION';
    protected $fillable = array('componente_formacion');

    public function campo_disciplinar(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CampoDisciplinar','id','componente_formacion_id');
    }

}
```

```html
class CampoDisciplinar extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'CAMPO_DISCIPLINAR';
    protected $fillable = array(
        'campo_disciplinar',
        'componente_formacion_id'
    );

    public function componente_formacion(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ComponenteFormacion','id','componente_formacion_id');
    }

    public function disciplina(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Disciplina');
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cuál es el código que utilizas para obtener el resultado que nos muestras?

Comment: listo lo acabo de agregar!!

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando las relaciones invertidas, por lo cual solo obtienes un elemento, no sé como hayas diseñado tu aplicación, pero para que funcione el eager loading de la forma que quieres, debería ser así:

```
class ComponenteFormacion extends Model
{
    //...
    public function campo_disciplinar() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CampoDisciplinar');
    }
}


class CampoDisciplinar extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function componente_formacion() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ComponenteFormacion');
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero no hay forma, en que se pueda convertir en un arreglo? Acabo de hacer las relaciones como me dijiste y tengo los mismos resultado. No tendrás un ejemplo, o por fuerza tengo que hacer un BelongToMany?

Comment: Pues no sé hasta que punto necesites especificar las llaves primarias, me parece que es innecesario. He utilizado muchas veces Eager Loading en proyectos grandes, simplemente siguiendo la documentación, sin ningún problema, los ejemplos que provee la documentación son bastante útiles y está bien expliado.